# bxSlider jQuery plugin issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow, bxslider

I'm working on a website and I implemented bxSlider in it. I have a page in which there are many images (their class name is `.item`). When you click one of the images, an overlay window would show up and display content (with a few paragraphs) and after that there's a sldieshow.

Problem is that I'm calling bxSlider right after document.ready, and since my overlay window is hidden (`display:none`), bxSlider won't load up properly.

And so I decided to put `$('.bxSlider').bxSlider();` inside `$('.item').click();`
and it works well.

But when Im closing the overlay window, and then showing it up again by clicking on `.item`, it will try to call the bxSlider function again, which will cause problems.

I tried to call `$('.bxSlider').destroySlide();` under `.close` (the div that closes the overlay window) but it doesn't work.

**JQuery:**

```
$(function(){
     //show bxslider
    $('a.show').click(function(){
        $('ul.bxslider').fadeIn();
         var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
        return false;
    });

    //hide bxslider
    $('a.hide').click(function(){
        $('ul.bxslider').fadeOut();
        return false;
    });
});
```

**Html:**

```
<a href class="show">Show Slider</a>
<a href class="hide">Hide Slider</a>
<br /><br />
<ul class="bxslider">
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" /></li>
</ul>
```

JSFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/GnBTm/3/)

Could anyone help me? [Here](http://bxslider.com/options)'s the plugin options:

Comment: can we have a playground such as jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com? also please update the question with the html markup, css, js code of what you tried so far.

Comment: Hi, of course. I was going to update my post. http://jsfiddle.net/GnBTm/3/

Comment: Can you please post the full code? i mean the code that you are using for **But when Im closing the overlay window, and then showing it up again by clicking on .item, it will try to call the bxSlider function again, which will cause problems.

I tried to call $('.bxSlider').destroySlide(); under .close (the div that closes the overlay window) but it doesn't work.**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood right your question, but this answer works for your problem ?

I updated the following part of your code:

```
//hide bxslider
$('a.hide').click(function(){
    $('ul.bxslider').fadeOut();
   var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
    slider.destroySlider();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GnBTm/5/

**UPDATE**

The code that I pasted it's part of this code below, you need to use equal this one, ok ?

```
$(function(){
     //show bxslider
    $('a.show').click(function(){
        $('ul.bxslider').fadeIn();
         var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
        return false;
    });

    //hide bxslider
    $('a.hide').click(function(){
        $('ul.bxslider').fadeOut();
        var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
        slider.destroySlider();
    });
});
```

Best Regards,
Rodrigo

Comment: Im copying and pasting your code, look what happens when I try to click on my slider create trigger: http://i.imgur.com/Y2e7Ye0.jpg and though it's copy and paste, seems like when im clicking on the close button bxSlider wont "get destroyed". Im so frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code was that you were not saving your bxslider handle. 
and the second problem was you were calling destroySlide and not destroySlider.

http://jsfiddle.net/4Nt7w/

Have a look at the solution in the fiddle.

```
 var slider = "";
 //show bxslider
$("#show").on('click',function(){
    $('ul.bxslider').fadeIn();
     slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
    return false;
});

//hide bxslider
$('#hide').on('click',function(){
    $('ul.bxslider').fadeOut();
    slider.destroySlider();
});
```

The HTML code

```
 <input type="button" id="show" class="show" value="Show Slider" />
 <input type="button" id="hide" class="hide" value="Hide Slider" />
 <br /><br />
 <ul class="bxslider">
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" /></li>
</ul>
```